# Hdri is not clear in blender background no matter what image texture I use

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, hdri

I'm not seeing the HDRI image in background. How to make it appear?

[image: The background hdri image is not showing]

Comment: Please don't use all caps in your texts. This is considered as rude for some people. Thank you.

Comment: if vklidus answer doesn't help, pls provide blend file. another reason might be, that you checked the transparent checkbox in render settings.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing ... You are using probably *Image Texture* node ... for world you need **Environment Texture** node with projection set to *Equirectangular*

[image]